# How do I extract a multilingual string in between an xml tag

Tags: java, regex, xml

I am trying to extract text in between an xml tag. The text in between the tag is multilingual.
For example:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    तुम्हारा नाम क्या है
</string>
```

I have tried to google it and got a few regexes but that didn't work
Here is one I have tried:

```
String str = "<string xmlns="+
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"+">"+
    "तुम्हारा नाम क्या है"+"</string>";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<String xmlns="+
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"+">(.+?)</string>");

final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

The given `String` format is

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    तुम्हारा नाम क्या है
</string>
```

and the expected output is:

```
तुम्हारा नाम क्या है
```

It's giving me an error

Comment: For one, regex is case sensitive. You pattern will only match `String [...]` with an uppercase "S"

Comment: Please keep in mind: you can't parse XML or HTML with regular expressions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la for the theory, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 for  fun ...

Comment: To add to Jägermeister’s point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pattern matches expected part and `$1` gives you expected result:

```
/<string .*?>(.*?)<\\/string>/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sO8wN8/4)

But **highly recommended** to stop doing that by regex ..! You have to find a HTML parser in JAVA and simply grab the content of `<string>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use regular expressions for parsing XML.  It will work in a few cases, but eventually it will fail.  See [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg) for a full explanation.

The easiest way to extract an element’s string content is with XPath:

```
String contents =
    XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().evaluate(
        "//*[local-name()='string']",
        new InputSource(new StringReader(str)));
```